# Not Getting correct model record from query on Eloquent RelationShip Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a 5.1 Laravel app. In that app I have a OnetoMany Relationship between Bussiness Model (named Negocio in spanish) and User Model. When I register my user I create a token and save it in users table to use the token on email confimation....

When the user confirms it account I want to use the token received by controller to create a directory with then name of the business that user is related to in 'public/negocios/'.

So in my controller to userconfirmartion I have:

```
public function emailConfirm($token)
{
    try {
        //getting the bussiness that user is related to
        $negocio = App\Negocio::with(['user' => function ($query) use($token) {
            $query->where('token', 'like', $token);
        }])->firstOrFail()->folderProfile();

        //Then we activate the user account
        $user = User::whereToken($token)->firstOrFail()->confirmEmail();
        return redirect('/login')->with('mensaje', '¡Su cuenta de usuario se ha activado, ahora puede iniciar sesión en su cuenta!');

    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return redirect('/login')->with('mensaje', 'Ya se ha confirmado a este usuario, solo inicie sesión ¬¬');
    }
}
```

In my Business Model I have the function to create the directory getting the bussiness name as the name of the directory:

```
public function folderProfile()
{
    $name = str_replace(' ', '', $this->nombre_negocio);
    $ruta_a_public = public_path().'/negocios/';
    $ruta_a_public .= $name;
    File::makeDirectory($ruta_a_public, $mode = 0777, true, true);
}
```

The problem is probing the code on `php artisan tinker` Eloquent gets all my bussiness recorded on database not just the business that user is related to.

It'd be appreciated from you if you could tell me the best way to make my "query" work as expected

The part that fails is (on business model):

```
$negocio = App\Negocio::with(['user' => function ($query) use($token) {
            $query->where('token', 'like', $token);
        }])->firstOrFail()->folderProfile();
```

I based it on what I read in https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

**EDIT:**
In my Negocio model(bussiness model in spanish):

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'negocio', 'codigo_negocio');
}
```

And in User Model I have this:

```
public function negocio()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Negocio', 'negocio', 'codigo_negocio');
}
```

Thanks guys... Sorry for this long post.

Comment: Hi Elotgamu,
Please, can you update your post to provide us a simple description about your tables to see the real relation between the user table and the bussines model?

Comment: Edited... Added my model relationships between User and Business model

Answer (score 0):

It's a diffent logic but maybe help:

```
//First search for the user
$user = App\User::where('token','like','%' . $token . '%')->first();

//Then search for the business
$negocio = App\Negocio::where('user_id',$user->id)->first();
```

Do not forget to define the relations between the tables.

By the way, you forget the % here:

```
$query->where('token', 'like', '%' . $token . '%');
```

If you looking for exact the same token, you should use this:

```
Something::where('token',$token)
```

Comment: Yeah I got this approach too, but the problem is that my business model **has** many user.. and user belongs to a business.

Comment: So I cannot get the Business. I tried looking for the exact token as you adviced but I get a Eloquent collection with all my recorded business. So the problem is still there... Thanks for answering and helping me... :)

Comment: I think your model is not correct, here is an example from the docs:

`$this->hasMany('App\Something', 'foreign_key', 'local_key')`

if you use first() or find() method, you can not get back more than one business.

Comment: Mmmm I don't see that way. Well, I think I followed laravel's model guides on docs because negocio is my foreign key on users table that  references negocio PK(which is codigo_negocio) ... And I get all my users related to my negocio model. And I cant reach the reverse of the realtionship, too.. So, please tell me where am I not getting the laravel way on models... Thanks @szebasztian for all you help...

Answer (score 0):

After further reading on laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships The way that works for me and get the expected record is:

```
$negocio = App\Negocio::whereHas('user', function ($query) use($token) {
            $query->where('token', $token);
        })->firstOrFail()->folderProfile();
```

This way I get the right business that token's owner is related to...
Thanks @szebasztian for some new tips for me about building querys on eloquent ORM.